# Possible Memory leak with NSDate in Struct

Tags: ios, struct, nsstring, nsdate, exc-bad-access

```
//h file

struct runSTRUCT{
   NSDate *RunDateTime;
} ;

 //m file

struct runSTRUCT run;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
   dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterNoStyle;
   [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy   HH:mm"];
   run.RunDateTime = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"12/02/2012   12:22"];
   NSString *dateTimeStr = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:run.RunDateTime];
   [dateFormatter release]; 
}
```

This all works fine. Then when I click a button and make a string from the date, it gives me EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

```
-(IBAction)respondButtonPressed:(id)sender{
   NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
   dateFormatter2.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterNoStyle;
   [dateFormatter2 setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy   HH:mm"];
   NSString *dateTimeStr = [dateFormatter2 stringFromDate:run.RunDateTime]; 
   [dateFormatter2 release]; 
}
```

When I look in the console and print description, it generally shows 1 of two things:

1. The program being debugged was signaled while in a function called from GDB.
   GDB has restored the context to what it was before the call.
   To change this behavior use "set unwindonsignal off"
   Evaluation of the expression containing the function (CFShow) will be abandoned.
   The program being debugged was signaled while in a function called from GDB.
   GDB has restored the context to what it was before the call.
   To change this behavior use "set unwindonsignal off"
   Evaluation of the expression containing the function (CFShow) will be abandoned.
2. Or "run.runDateTime" is some random variable

EDIT: I'm not sure if I put these in the right place because it still doesn't work(I probably didn't).

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
      [super viewDidLoad];
      NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
      dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterNoStyle;
      [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy   HH:mm"];
      run.RunDateTime = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"12/02/2012   12:22"];
      NSString *dateTimeStr = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:run.RunDateTime];

     [run.RunDateTime retain];

      [dateFormatter release]; 
}

-(IBAction)respondButtonPressed:(id)sender{
   NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
   dateFormatter2.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterNoStyle;
   [dateFormatter2 setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy   HH:mm"];
   NSString *dateTimeStr = [dateFormatter2 stringFromDate:run.RunDateTime]; 

   [dateFormatter2 release]; 
}
```

I also have a couple of NSStrings in the struct and they work fine.

Comment: run -> RunDateTime... try this. This is how you usually access data in a struct.

Comment: That doen't seem to be working.

run->RunDateTime and run -> RunDateTime both come up with "invalid type argument of '->'

Comment: You only need the retain in the viewDidLoad method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to retain RunDateTime after you assign/create it from the date formatter.

```
 [run.RunDateTime retain];
```

Make sure to release it in your dealloc!

Comment: It works! Thank you very much! I forgot to retain another variable so it works now. Thanks!